How to get SUM value from foreach smarty syntax?
How to get SUM value from foreach smarty syntax?, like this:
{foreach from=$worklist item=w name=costs}
    {$w.price}
{/foreach} 
{assign var='allPrice' value=(???)}


Thank you, that is the same as what i asked..
